# Is it possible to access a member variable of a pair from queue member function directly?

Tags: c++, queue, std-pair

I have a doubt about the queue member function back and front, is it possible to access an element of a pair (first,second) directly from the queue or do I have to make a temporary variable to be able to print it out let's say with  `std::cout`

What I want to know if it's possible to do something like this: `std:cout<<q.front().first;`

Thanks for reading and passing by, any info is appreciated, here's my actual code

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    queue<pair<int,int> > q;
    q.push(make_pair(2,0));
    q.push(make_pair(2,0));
    q.push(make_pair(2,90));
    pair<int,int> tmp;
    tmp=q.front();
    q.front()=make_pair(tmp.first,tmp.second+1);
    tmp=q.front();

    cout<<"Second element of Top "<< tmp.second<<endl;
        tmp=q.back();
        cout<<"Second element of Back "<< tmp.second<<endl;
}
```

This is the output I get but would like to get it directly fromt the console with out a temporary variable.

```
Second element of Top 1
Second element of Back 90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the first element, aka `.front()`, however, you are removing it from the `queue` with `.pop()` immediately afterwards. Remove `q.pop()` and you get the output you want.

And yes, `std::cout<<q.front().first;` (assuming `:` is a mistake) is valid.

`.front()` returns a reference to the element.

Comment: This is the answer to the previous removed question

Comment: Thanks, I checked my code again and you are right, I edited the question and added a brief comment on why I deleted the part of modifying the value) what I still have the doubt is about the console output part.